# Was there ever reasoning presented for the size of a satoshi (i.e., the minimum amount of bitcoin that can be transacted)?

Tags: satoshi

If not, what are the prevailing critiques and concerns of that design choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like most of these internal choices in the Bitcoin system, it's not really explained by the author and can't be easily changed even if anybody had a strong objection to it. Internally all values are 64 bit integers, and just displayed to the user as `value / 1e8`.

[image: bitcoin 0.1]

The original wxBitcoin releases displayed two decimal places of precision.